# Credentials profile file not being recognized by AWS SDK

Tags: php, laravel-5, configuration-files, aws-sdk

I am recieving empty objects for key/secret while using AWS credentials files

```
[credentials:protected] => Aws\Common\Credentials\Credentials Object
(
    [key:protected] => 
    [secret:protected] => 
    [token:protected] => 
    [ttd:protected] => 1
)
```

As well as

```
[service] => sqs
[base_url] => https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[key] => 
[secret] => 
[token] => 
[token.ttd] => 
[credentials.cache] => 
[credentials.cache.key] => 
[credentials.client] => 
[client.backoff] => Guzzle\Plugin\Backoff\BackoffPlugin Object
.........
```

The code I am using is extremely straight forward...

```
Class Foo
{
    private sqsClient = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sqsClient = SqsClient::factory([
            'profile' => 'default',
            'region'  => 'us-east-1',
        ]);

        header('content-type: text/plain'); print_r($this->sqsClient); die;
    }
}

$sqs = New Foo();
```

credentials as well as config files are both located in `~/.aws/{config,credentials}`

config

```
[default]
output = json
region = us-east-1
```

credentials

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Why aren't these being read in correctly? This is using Laravel 5.0. Composer slice as follows

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
    "laravel/installer": "~1.2",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~2.0",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.8.*"
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel by defaults load the AWS credentials, so we can use like bellow.

```
    use Aws\Sqs\SqsClient;

    $sqsClient = new SqsClient([
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'version' => '2012-11-05'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was due to file permissions on `~/.aws/credentials` being owned by root not user